# What's the probability that a license plate contains one A and one 7?

Tags: combinatorics

A license plate is composed of 4 letters and 3 digits. Whats the probability that a license plate contains at least one A and one 7?

Comment: You need to add self-study tag because this is home work, also you need to describe your attempt at solving it. this is not the place to ask people to your assignments. see the guide here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: I guess that you are supposed to assume that all (26?) letters and numbers/digits (10?) are equally likely to occur in any of the 4/3 spots for the letters/digits and independent from the other letters/digits?

Answer (score 1):

To give a clue, let us consider the simpler case when you are rather interested in the probability P that there is at least one 7 OR one A.

Without further assumption, I suppose the licence letters and digits and completely drawn at random.
The trick is to consider the complementary:

$P = 1 - P$(noA and no 7)

$P$(noA and no 7) = $P$(noA) * $P$(no7) $= (25/26)^4 * (9/10)^3 $

Comment: This answer looks incorrect, because the complement of "at least one A and one 7" is "no A's" **or** "no 7's."

Comment: Indeed. I did not answer the original question. I answered the simpler: "there is at least one A or one 7"

Comment: But by not stating the question you are answering, you are creating grounds for confusion.  Please clarify your answer.

Comment: Done. Thanks for your vigilance.